# Regular expression for conditionally formatting a number string

Tags: c#, regex, string

*orginal question removed*

---

I am looking for a Regular Expression which will format a string containing of special characters, characters and numbers into a string containing only numbers.
There are special cases in which it’s not enough to only replace all non-numeric characters with “” (empty).

1.) Zero in brackets.

- If there are only zeros in a bracket (0) these should be removed if it is the first bracket pair. (The second bracket pair containing only zeros should not be removed)

2.) Leading zero.

- All leading zero should be removed (ignoring brackets)

Examples for better understanding:

- `123 (0) 123 would be 123123 (zero removed)`
- `(0) 123 -123 would be 123123(zero and all other non-numeric characters removed)`
- `2(0) 123 (0) would be 21230 (first zero in brackets removed)`
- `20(0)123023(0) would be 201230230 (first zero in brackets removed)`
- `00(0)1 would be 1(leading zeros removed)`
- `001(1)(0) would be 110 (leading zeros removed)`
- `0(0)02(0) would be 20 (leading zeros removed)`
- `123(1)3 would be 12313 (characters removed)`

Comment: What language / flavor of regex?

Comment: @ExplosionPills C# .NET flavor (see tags)...

Comment: `[^\d]` is a regex for anything that *is not* a digit, so I'm not sure how you are intending to use this regex.

Comment: Tim Rogers I fixed it, Im replacing all found non numbers with "".

Comment: Do you mean just `(0)` or any digit in parentheses?

Comment: iamnotmaynard see example 2

Comment: Could you clarify your new requirements? You now say "if the `(0)` is not the first bracket pair, it should be handled as normal", presumably if it's not at the beginning as in the third example, but your first example seems to conflict with that.

Comment: In the future, please ask a question only once you have determined your exact and final requirements. Repeatedly changing and adding requirements is frustrating and counterproductive.

Comment: @Wiseguy I complety understand your concern and to be honest the additional requirements where found while testing the low requirement version.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not just pointing it out because it can be frustrating, but because it's in your best interest. If you change an old question, most people won't see it. And if someone finds this question, the answers might be out of date and no longer useful. If you need to change your question or ask a followup question, it's probably better to ask a new one so that more people will see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) <s>to match `(0)` only if it's *not* at the beginning of the string,</s> and replace with empty string as you're doing.

<sub>*(original solution removed)*</sub>

---

*Updated **again** to reflect new requirements*

Matches leading zeroes, matches `(0)` only if it's the first parenthesized item, and matches any non-digit characters:

```
^[0\D]+|(?<=^[^(]*)\(0\)|\D
```

Note that most regex engines do not support variable-length lookbehinds (i.e., the use of quantifiers like `*`), so this will only work in a few regex engines -- .NET's being one of them.

```
^[0\D]+      # zeroes and non-digits at start of string
|            # or
(?<=^[^(]*)  # preceded by start of string and only non-"(" chars
\(0\)        # "(0)"
|            # or
\D           # non-digit, equivalent to "[^\d]"
```

(*tested at [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester/)*)

---

You've changed and added requirements several times now. For multiple rules like this, you're probably better off coding for them individually. It could become complicated and difficult to debug if one condition matches and causes another condition not to match when it should. For example, in separate steps:

1. Remove parenthesized items as necessary.
2. Remove non-digit characters.
3. Remove leading zeroes.

But if you absolutely need these three conditions all matched in a single regular expression (not recommended), here it is.

Comment: This was the correct answer for my question, but I just discovered that my questions was not precise enough

Comment: @Anubis1233 Updated again to reflect changing requirements.

Comment: @Anubis1233 Once again updated to reflect your changed and additional requirements. At this point, you should probably just apply these requirements separately.

Comment: wow you really did a good job here. thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should be pretty near the one you're searching for.

```
(^[^\d])|([^\d](0[^\d])?)+
```

(You can replace everything that is caught by an empty string)

**EDIT :**

Your request evolved, and is now to complex to be treatd with a single pass. Assuming you **always** got a space before a bracket group, you can use those passes (keep this order) :

```
string[] entries = new string[7] {
    "800 (0) 123 - 1",
    "800 (1) 123",
    "(0)321 123",
    "1 (0) 1",
    "1 (12) (0) 1",
    "1 (0) (0) 1",
    "(9)156 (1) (0)"
};
foreach (string entry in entries)
{
    var output = Regex.Replace(entry , @"\(0\)\s*\(0\)", "0");
    output = Regex.Replace(output, @"\s\(0\)", "");
    output = Regex.Replace(output, @"[^\d]", "");
    System.Console.WriteLine("---");
    System.Console.WriteLine(entry);
    System.Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Comment: Reading my regex afterward, I find it should remove it, but I didn't get any problem with RegExr, my bad. Anyway, now the request evolved and truly starts to be hard !

Answer (score 1):

Regexes get much, much simpler if you can use multiple passes. I think you could do a first pass to drop your (0) if it's not the first thing in a string, then follow it with stripping out the non-digits:

```
var noMidStrParenZero = Regex.Replace(text, "^([^(]+)\(0\)", "$1");
var finalStr = Regex.Replace(noMidStrParenZero, "[^0-9]", "");
```

Avoids a lot of regex craziness, and it's also self-documenting to an extent.

EDIT: this version should work with your new examples too.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:     # start grouping
    ^   # start of string
    |   # OR
    ^\( # start of string followed by paren
    |   # OR
    \d  # a digit
)       # end grouping
(0+)    # capture any number of zeros
|       # OR
([1-9]) # capture any non-zero digit
```

[This works for all of your example strings](http://rubular.com/r/obcVC0sW4N), but the entire expression does match the `(` followed by the zero.  You can use `Regex.Matches` to get the match collection using a global match and then join all of the matched groups into a string to get numbers only (or just remove any non-numbers).